# Flag variety as monoid and Schubert calculus

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus

The lattice of linear subspaces in a vector space V can be provided with a structure of monoid by considering the subspace generated by the union of two subspaces as the monoid operation.
When looking at flags in V on could consider the sum of two flags using the monoid operation on subspaces. I guess it is then possible to provide flags with a structure of monoid (algebraic monoid ?).
How is reflected this monoid structure in terms of Schubert varities or Schubert classes or Schubert polynomials etc. ?
Thank you!

Comment: This "sum" is not well-defined. Take $\dim V=2$, two flags given by lines $\ell_1,\ell_2$ in $V$. What is the sum?

Comment: As a sum, this would be the smallest linear subspace containing both $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ that is we would have the partial flag $0 \subset V$ if $\ell_1 \neq \ell_2$ or $0\subset \ell_1\subset V$ if $\ell_1 = \ell_2$.

Comment: But this is not in the same flag variety... Maybe you want to take the disjoint union of all flag varieties built on $V$? That doesn't sound too promising.

Comment: Yes i agree. Since i'm learning the topic, my question may be non-sense. However it seems to me that on the set of all partial or complete flags of V, this sum is well defined. My question is then: is there somehow  a ”trace” of this in Schubert calculus...

Comment: The answer is no, because Schubert calculus deals with the variety of flags with a fixed type (:= dimension of the subspaces appearing in the flag).

Comment: Ok i understand. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: There is a way to multiply all flags in a join semilattice (not just the maximal ones).  The product of $a_1<a_2<\cdots < a_k$ with $b_1<\cdots <b_s$ is the flag obtained from $a_1<...< a_k\leq a_k\vee b_1\leq\cdots \leq a_k\vee b_s$ by removing repetitions as you read from left to right.  This is called the Rhodes expansion.

Comment: Thank you for this last information! Is there a good reference for this ?

Comment: @FreddyG, you have to ping people in comments for them to be notified of your comments.  You can find a version of this and other references in section 3.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1159.pdf

Comment: The closest I know uses the direct sum operation $Gr(a,a+b) \times Gr(c,c+d) \to Gr(a+c,a+b+c+d)$. If you use the induced map on homology to define a bigraded ring, and give that total homology an obvious basis coming from Schubert varieties, you get something that's almost the ring of symmetric functions (i.e. has structure constants = Littlewood-Richardson).